# send header value using HttpUrlConnection

Tags: android, get, httpurlconnection, http-token-authentication

I have trying to send response to server using authentication value which, it provides me at login time. The server only accepts requests when that value is sent. However it works well with [postman (see snapshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twfzo.png) but not with my code.

code

```
 URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            String token = "" + new String(accessToken);
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("AuthToken", token);
            con.setReadTimeout(15000);
            con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            con.setDoOutput(false);
```

I also have tried in that way

```
String token = "AuthToken :" + new String(accessToken);
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
```

Comment: Refer this code:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/32225262/3946958e

Comment: I am sending request over GET method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one

```
URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        String token = "" + new String(accessToken);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("AuthToken", token);
        con.setReadTimeout(15000);
        con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        con.setDoOutput(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this one -

```
**
 * HTTP request types
 */
public static final int POST_TYPE   = 1;
public static final int GET_TYPE    = 2;
public static final int PUT_TYPE    = 3;
public static final int DELETE_TYPE = 4;

/**
 * HTTP request header constants
 */
public static final String CONTENT_TYPE         = "Content-Type";
public static final String ACCEPT_ENCODING      = "Accept-Encoding";
public static final String CONTENT_ENCODING     = "Content-Encoding";
public static final String ENCODING_GZIP        = "gzip";
public static final String MIME_FORM_ENCODED    = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
public static final String MIME_TEXT_PLAIN      = "text/plain";

private InputStream performRequest(final String contentType, final String url, final String user, final String pass,
    final Map<String, String> headers, final Map<String, String> params, final int requestType) 
            throws IOException {

    DefaultHttpClient client = HTTPClientFactory.newClient();

    client.getParams().setParameter(HttpProtocolParams.USER_AGENT, mUserAgent);

    // add user and pass to client credentials if present
    if ((user != null) && (pass != null)) {
        client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, pass));
    }

    // process headers using request interceptor
    final Map<String, String> sendHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if ((headers != null) && (headers.size() > 0)) {
        sendHeaders.putAll(headers);
    }
    if (requestType == HTTPRequestHelper.POST_TYPE || requestType == HTTPRequestHelper.PUT_TYPE ) {
        sendHeaders.put(HTTPRequestHelper.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType);
    }
    // request gzip encoding for response
    sendHeaders.put(HTTPRequestHelper.ACCEPT_ENCODING, HTTPRequestHelper.ENCODING_GZIP);

    if (sendHeaders.size() > 0) {
        client.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {

            public void process(final HttpRequest request, final HttpContext context) throws HttpException,
                IOException {
                for (String key : sendHeaders.keySet()) {
                    if (!request.containsHeader(key)) {
                        request.addHeader(key, sendHeaders.get(key));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //.... code omitted ....//

}
```

Reference - [Send HTTP GET request with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442791/send-http-get-request-with-header)

Comment: I want to do this with httpUrlConnection

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
String token = new String(new Base64().encode(accessToken.getBytes()));
con.setRequestProperty("AuthToken", token);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET"); with myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Request Method", "GET");

Please find the code below:

```
URL myURL = new URL(serviceURL);
HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)myURL.openConnection();
String userCredentials = "username:password";
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + postData.getBytes().length);
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
myURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
myURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
myURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Comment: I need to do this using get method

Comment: You can do the same with get